# Thread Syn in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying executing a program and wait the output but this run under a thread but crashed the program when
try wait the output with 'WaitForSingleObject' of CreateProcess().

also I want will close handle of thread created when finish the process created by 'CreateProcess'

```
class test{
    public:
        static void fun2(void * args){
        /*...*/
            if (!CreateProcess( NULL, Args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo)) {
                return GetLastError();      
            }

            WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
            ULONG rc;
            if(!GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, &rc)){
                status = 0;
            }
        /*...*/
        }
        void fun1(){
        /* ... */
            HANDLE h = NULL; 
            h = CreateThread(NULL, 0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)fun2,&data,0,0);
            if(h!=NULL){
                printf("OK\n");
            }
        /* ... */
        }
};

int main(){
    test t;
    t.fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `std::thread` and the synchronization mechanisms available from there?

Comment: I'm new with the threads, I will try, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem (in the *fragment* you provided) is with this part: `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)fun2`.

Your `fun2` is incompatible with ThreadProc. [ThreadProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx) is declared as:

```
    DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter);
```

`WINAPI` resolves to `__stdcall` which is another calling convention from the default `cdecl`. As a quick fix you can add `WINAPI` to the `fun2` declaration. This may help. If it doesn't, provide a more complete example (read how to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), something people can *compile* and *reproduce* the error.

Or just use `std::thread`, which will be more portable.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

class test{
    public:
        static void fun2(void * args){
            printf("OK from thread\n");
        }
        void fun1(){
            std::thread t([]{
                fun2(nullptr);
            });
            printf("OK\n");
            t.join();
        }
};

int main(){
    test t;
    t.fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

Beware of the lifecycle of `std::thread` - if it's destroyed while the thread is still running, the whole program will terminate. A call to `join` before `std::thread` goes out of scope thus ensures proper sequence of action.

Comment: thanks and how to I can close thread when fun2() finish or this will close when closed fun()?

Comment: thanks but i can't pass a struct to fun2().  fun2(&mystr);

Comment: The `[]` construct is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx), you can pass your input data between the brackets.

Comment: Thanks so much @RustyX

Comment: `That's why the application crashes. ` of course no, in this concrete case swap __stdcall to __cdecl despite wrong, no produce crash. faster this is `,&data` - invisible how it defined, but if it local var - can be root of crash.